# VGA input on HP Envy 17 3D

Tags: vga, input, hp-envy

Can `HP Envy 17 3D` do `VGA` input?

There is a `VGA` connection on the side, but I don't know if it is only output, or if it can be used for input too... I tried to google, but couldn't find any information.

The VGA source is an old game console, so I don't think it is possible to use any USB tricks or other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is VGA output only.  Without a dedicated video capture device, you will not be able to see external video from another source.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Do you think there might be a way to somehow connect the VGA source to output on the laptop screen?

Comment: The short answer is no.  Although it is *technically* possible, the amount of time and effort would not be worth it.  The simplest solution would be to buy an LCD monitor with a VGA input.  They are dirt cheap, if you get a used one.

Comment: Too bad... I was hoping there is something I could do to make it work.